# Davening Shema with minyan

Tags: shema

I find my minyan moves so fast through the paragraphs and brachot after the Shema, I have to skip forward after “emes” to join them with “kadosh kadosh kadosh” etc.  is this permissible?  Do i have to go back after davening to recite the omitted passages?

Comment: Hi you are not allowed to skip the berachot after shema, "veyatziv", even to catch up to kadosh x3 (kedusha in chazan's repetition of amida). If I am understanding you correctly? If so better for you to just go ahead of everyone else and try to time it so you reach Amida with them. Or find a slower minyan